# Office 365 Power Shell to Add Users based on department to a Shared Mailbox

Tags: powershell, office365

I have the code below which isn't quite working and would appreciate any advice. I have basic coding skills with powershell so please forgive me if my statement is completely wrong. I am attempting to grab users based on there department variable which works and then add each user to a shared mailbox which doesn't. I think the issue is with the variable or for loop as the commands manually ran work fine.

Thank you in advance.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionURI https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential –Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Import-PSSession $Session
Import-Module msonline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
$DL = Get-MsolUser -All -Department "Staff" | select-object UserPrincipalName
ForEach ($UserPrincipalName in $DL) {
$DL | % {Add-MailboxPermission "shared-mailbox@domain.com"} -User $_ -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All}
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all users with specific department, you can use 'where' conditon. And then you can pipe the result to add full access permission to the shared mailbox.

```html
Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.department -eq "XXX"} | foreach{
 $UPN=$_.UserPrincipalName
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Shared MB name" -User $UPN -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
}
```